# Modifying visual studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, components

When i want to modify visual studio components( adding new one and not deleting any) do i modify just clicking for new one and leaving those already installed or do I unclick those before. I don't have much space and wonder if it will install some components again.
Image: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybgHJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the components that you want, it won't duplicate the ones you already have installed.